# How to get the categories of the records

Tags: django, django-models

I have several hundred thousand svn commit record in my django database , and I defined the BranchName field to save each commit's related branch info.

By using django admin site , I can define *list_filter   = ('BranchName',)*  to get the branch name categories and filter the related records

My question is , is there any method to get this branch name list by the django API directly? (define QuerySet or filter)

[image: admin site]

Comment: I really appreciate if anyone can help on it，thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) and [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) in the QuerySet API reference.

Assuming the following model:

```
class SVNCommit(models.Model):
    branch_name = models.CharField()
```

You would get a list of the distinct values from the branch_name field like this:

```
branch_names = SVNCommit.objects.values_list('branch_name', flat=True).distinct()
```